# why header event is not getting triggered in nodejs

Tags: node.js, stream

I have this code in my one of the application.

```js
 const readStream= fs.createReadStream('xlsx file path here');
        readStream.on('header', (header) => {
            console.log('header event');
           console.log(header);
        })
        .on('data',  function(file) {
            console.log('data event');  
            
        });
```

This code works fine in other application but when I copied same code into another app it's not triggering "header" event. however "data" event is getting trigger. tried with same xlsx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused with a library, built-in streams, such as `fs.createReadStream` does not have a header event.

[csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) most likely

```js
fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('headers', (headers) => {
    console.log(`First header: ${headers[0]}`)
  })
```